# how to run an OpenModelica OMPython example model without a Load file error?

Tags: python-3.x, openmodelica

I am trying to simulate an OpenModelica example model using ModelicaSystem python module. But I am getting the following error in its constructor. As follows:

code:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pyfmi
from OMPython import OMCSessionZMQ
from OMPython import ModelicaSystem

omc = OMCSessionZMQ()

model_path = '/usr/lib/omlibrary/Modelica 3.2.3/Electrical/'

omc.sendExpression('loadModel(model_path + Machines.mo)')

mod = ModelicaSystem(model_path + 'Machines.mo','Modelica.Electrical.Machines.Examples.AsynchronousInductionMachines.AIMC_Inverter')
```

error:

```
loadFile Error: Error: Failed to insert class Machines within Modelica.Electrical;

 the available classes were:
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I admit the [User's Guide on OpenModelica Python Interface](https://www.openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/ompython.html) is quite unclear at the moment. Also `ModelicaSystem` is missing an easy way to load a model from a standard library in your path.

`loadModel` is a function to load the Modelica Standard Library (MSL), see [OpenModelica Scripting API for loadModel](https://www.openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/scripting_api.html#loadmodel). You can't load a file with it.
If you want to use `omc.sendExpression` you need to use [loadFile](https://www.openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/scripting_api.html#loadfile) to load a specific file from the Python interface.

If you want to create a `ModelicaSystem` for a MSL example I would suggest to load all of the MSL package:

```
from OMPython import OMCSessionZMQ
from OMPython import ModelicaSystem

omc = OMCSessionZMQ()
model_path = '/usr/lib/omlibrary/Modelica 3.2.3/package.mo'
mod = ModelicaSystem(model_path, 'Modelica.Electrical.Machines.Examples.AsynchronousInductionMachines.AIMC_Inverter')
```

You can't load only `/usr/lib/omlibrary/Modelica 3.2.3/Electrical/Modelica 3.2.3/Electrical/Machines.mo`, because it is still depending on the MSL 3.2.3.
In OMEdit you get a more precise error message, but in Python you'll only get the first line of that message.

Comment: Hi, how does this work with dependency within same package?
I was adding the dependent model on 3rd argument of Modelica system, but got :
`Error: Cannot instantiate package.folder1.folder2.Folder3.dependentmodel due to class specialization PACKAGE.` instead

Comment: Please ask a new question with a minimal example.

Comment: posted on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69280398/ompython-using-custom-model-with-external-package